# $f(x)=\int_0^x\sin(t^2-t+x)dt$. Find $f''(x)+f'(x)$

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives

$f(x)=\int_0^x\sin(t^2-t+x)dt$. Find $f''(x)+f'(x)$.

Using leibnitz integral rule,

$$f'(x)=\int_0^x\cos(t^2-t+x)+\sin(x^2)dt$$
$$f''(x)=-\int_0^x\sin(t^2-t+x)dt+2x\cos(x^2)$$

Answer given is $(2x+1)\cos(x^2)$. I wont get this if I add $f''(x)+f'(x)$

Comment: your first derivative is $$f'(x)=\int_0^x\cos(t^2-t+x)dt+\sin(x^2)$$

Comment: And second one is $$f''(x)=-\int_0^x\sin(t^2-t+x)dt+(2x+1)\cos(x^2)$$

Comment: Are you sure you are asked to find out $f''+f'$? Might be $f''+f$ by looking at the given answer. If it is then the answer is evident from second derivative.

Comment: @KushalBhuyan. I am sure that you are correct : it must be $f''+f$. Otherwise, for $f''+f'$, it is a monster involving Fresnel integrals. One more typo probably in the textbook.

Comment: @KushalBhuyan possibly a printing error in the book.

Comment: @Aditya Yup, so it must be $f''+f$ then. So your problem is solved isn't it?

Comment: @KushalBhuyan yes. Post an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

P.S. :Since OP is convinced that it is asked to find $f''+f$.

Given $f(x)=\int_0^x\sin(t^2-t+x)dt$.

By Leibniz differentiation under the integral rule,

$$f'(x)=\int_0^x\cos(t^2-t+x)dt+\sin(x^2)$$
$$f''(x)=-\int_0^x\sin(t^2-t+x)dt+(2x+1)\cos(x^2)$$
$$f''(x)=-f(x)+(2x+1)\cos(x^2)$$
$$f''(x)+f(x)=(2x+1)\cos(x^2)$$